# Setting class variables inside Tornado application

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado application structured like below:

```
...

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get():
        ...

class MyOtherHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post():
        ...

class MyClass(object):
    my_class_variable = {}
    ...

    def my_method_one():
        # access my_class_variable
        ...

    def my_method_two():
        # access my_class_variable
        ...
```

Inside which, I have a class variable `my_class_variable` inside my custom class. I want to set this class variable from outside of `MyClass`, e.g. inside one of the handlers. Hence my question, is it a good practice in a Tornado application to modify class variables directly within methods of handlers? e.g.

```
MyClass.my_class_variable[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Handlers often need to interact with other classes, in various ways.

Comment: thanks! But is there any situation where this design is not optimal?

Comment: @skyork, when you have really heavy load(1000+ rps) per tornado instance - complex class-handler interaction can deal bad thing with you. Other way everything is fine with this scheme, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks "dirty" to me... It's difficult to tell without knowing the specific problem, but I would find it much simpler and cleaner to just pass to `my_method_one` and `my_method_two` methods whatever parameters are needed, rather then setting some class-level attributes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The class variable is needed because it acts a 'global/shared' variable for all the instances of `MyClass`. However, I also need to set this class variable based on user's POST requests via a handler, from outside of `MyClass`, hence my question above. What you've suggested seems to get rid of 'my_class_variable' altogether, which is probably not suitable for my use case here.

Comment: How is that cleaner, if the methods are just modifying the class variable? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292631/are-accessors-in-python-ever-justified

Comment: @ColeMaclean I was suggesting of removing the class variable altogether.